# Submit Multiple Form on One page in php using ajax For Send mail

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

In Functionality, I have 5 button for submit contact form on one page. This form is opened the popup.

When I send the contact form on php using ajax call on same page for single form, I get the data by mail

But When I send the contact form on php using ajax call on same page for multiple form, I do not get the data by mail.

Now, my confusion is that how to send the data by mail using ajax.

right now, I am sharing the source code as I have done in my functionality.

Hope!! I will get the solution.

**index.php**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--  This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com  -->
    <!--  Last Published: Wed Jul 18 2018 07:29:42 GMT+0000 (UTC)  -->
    <html data-wf-page="5b43680820a14a0ddeaf82d3" data-wf-site="5b43680820a14adf17af82d2">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Montreal</title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
      <meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
      <style>.w-form-formrecaptcha {   margin-bottom: 8px; }</style>
      <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/app-velocity-montreal.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">WebFont.load({  google: {    families: ["Heebo:100,300,regular,500,700,800,900","Sriracha:regular"]  }});</script>
      <!-- [if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif] -->
      <script type="text/javascript">!function(o,c){var n=c.documentElement,t=" w-mod-";n.className+=t+"js",("ontouchstart"in o||o.DocumentTouch&&c instanceof DocumentTouch)&&(n.className+=t+"touch")}(window,document);</script>
      <link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
      <link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/img/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
      <!--  Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics  -->
      <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-54050564-1"></script>
      <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-54050564-1');
    </script>
      <style>
    .sticky  { position: fixed; top: 0; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85); }
    .w-slider-dot { width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: rgba(152, 168, 185, 0.54); margin: 0 4.5px .5em; }
    .w-slider-dot.w-active { background-color: #00beff; height: 15px; border-radius: 8px !important; }
    .w-slider-nav { bottom: -3em; padding: 0px; }
    .client-blue-bg:after { content: ""; position: absolute; border-left: 38px solid #e5f8ff; border-top: 26px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; right: -5.2em; width: 36.02px; height: 0; top: 0;}
    .client-purple-bg:before { content: ""; position: absolute; border-right: 38px solid #f9fafe; border-top: 26px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; left: -5.2em; width: 36.02px; height: 0; top: 0; }
    .navbar.sticky { min-height: 60px;}
    .navbar.sticky a.brand { padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 13px; }
    .navbar.sticky nav a { padding-top: 19px; padding-bottom: 17px; }
    .navbar.sticky .menu-button { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
    .software-freelancer-block a { text-decoration: none; }
    .w-slider-arrow-left, .w-slider-arrow-right { color: rgba(152, 168, 185, 0.54); width: 40px; }
    .w-slider-arrow-left:hover, .w-slider-arrow-right:hover { color: #00beff; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
     .wrapper { max-width: 1044px; }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
     .banner { background-size: 50% auto; }
      .ux-wireframe-img { height: 205px; }
      .w-nav-overlay      { top: 80px; z-index: 99 !important;}
      .w-slider-nav       { bottom: -5em; }
      .right-arrow       { right: -28px; }
      .left-arrow        { left: -40px; }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
     .w-nav-overlay      { top: 80px; z-index: 99 !important;}
     .right-arrow        { right: -20px; font-size: 30px; }
     .left-arrow        { left: -25px; font-size: 30px; }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .client-purple-bg:before { display: none; }
      .client-blue-bg:after   { display: none; }
      .w-nav-overlay      { top: 80px; z-index: 99 !important;}
      .w-slider-nav       { bottom: -5em; }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     .w-nav-button.w--open { background-color: transparent;}
      .w--nav-menu-open   { background-color: #00beff; background-image: none; }
    }
    span.error {
      color: #e7040f;
      margin: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
    span.success {
      color: #008000;
      margin: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
    #loader {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
    .w-form-done {
      color: #008000;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- include Google hosted jQuery Library -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
       $("button").click(function() {
          var formID = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
          var formData = $("#"+formID).serialize();
          var formid = "#"+formID;
          if($("#"+formID)[0].checkValidity()) {
           $.ajax({
            url: "contact_form_mail.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            success: function( data ) {
               // Handle success here
               if(data.fname == 'form1') {
                 var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (res.result === true) {

            }
                   } else if(data.fname == 'form2') {
                     var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (res.result === true) {

            }
                   }

            },
            error: function(e) {
              // Handle error here
              console.log(e);
            },
            timeout: 30000
          });
         } else {
          alert("Please enter name and message");
         }
       });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="modal-wrapper" data-ix="model-interaction">
        <div class="contact-wrapper w-clearfix"><a href="#" class="close-model w-inline-block" data-ix="close-lmodel-interaction"><img src="images/form-close-btn_1form-close-btn.png" class="image-25"></a>
          <div class="div-block-2 form-left w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/contact-form-img.svg" class="image-26"></div>
          <div class="form-right">
            <h1 class="heading-22">Contact Us</h1>
            <div class="w-form">
              <form id="form1" name="ContactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                <ul class="msgBox"></ul>
                <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data! </span>
                <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="form1">
                <input type="text" class="text-field fname w-input" maxlength="256" name="yourname" data-name="YourName" placeholder="Your Name*" id="yourname" required="">
                <input type="text" class="text-field-2 w-input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="Email" placeholder="Email Address*" id="email" required="">
                <input type="text" class="text-field-3 w-input" maxlength="256" name="subject" data-name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" id="subject" required="">
                <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message*" maxlength="5000" data-name="message" required="" class="textarea w-input"></textarea>
              <!--  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1" data-wait="Please wait..." class="submit-button w-button">-->
                <button type="button">Submit</button>
                <div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="images/loader-img.gif" /></div>
                <div class="w-form-done" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
                   <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
                 </div>
                <div class="w-form-fail" id="w-form-fail" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
                   <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
                 </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="get-quote-wrapper" data-ix="get-quote-model-interction">
        <div class="contact-wrapper get-quote-form-wrapper w-clearfix"><a href="#" class="close-model close-get-model w-inline-block" data-ix="close-lmodel-interaction"><img src="images/form-close-btn_1form-close-btn.png" class="image-25" data-ix="close-get-quote-lmodel-interaction"></a>
          <div class="form-left w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/get-quote-bg.svg" class="image-27"></div>
          <div class="form-right">
            <h1 class="heading-22 get-quote-heading">Get a quote within 48 hours</h1>
            <div class="w-form">
             <form id="form2" name="ContactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
               <ul class="msgBox"></ul>
                <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data! </span>
                <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="form2">
                <input type="text" class="text-field fname get-fname w-input" maxlength="256" name="yourname" data-name="Your Name" placeholder="Your Name*" id="yourname" required="">
                <input type="text" class="text-field-2 get-email w-input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="Email" placeholder="Email Address*" id="email" required="">
                <input type="text" class="text-field-3 get-phone w-input" maxlength="256" name="phoneno" data-name="Phone Number" placeholder="Phone number*" id="phoneno" required="">
                <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="How can we help you? *" maxlength="5000" data-name="Message" required="" class="textarea get-msg w-input"></textarea>
              <!--  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit2" data-wait="Please wait..." class="submit-button w-button"> -->
                <button type="button">Submit</button>
                <div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="images/loader-img.gif" /></div>
                <div class="w-form-done" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
                   <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
                 </div>
                <div class="w-form-fail" id="w-form-fail" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
                   <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
                 </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="let-talk-wrapper" data-ix="let-talk-model-interction">
        <div class="contact-wrapper let-talk-form-wrapper w-clearfix"><a href="#" class="close-model close-let-model w-inline-block" data-ix="close-let-talk-lmodel-interaction"><img src="images/form-close-btn_1form-close-btn.png" class="image-25" data-ix="close-get-quote-lmodel-interaction"></a>
          <div class="form-left w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/lets-talk-img.svg" class="image-28"></div>
          <div class="form-right">
            <h1 class="heading-22 let-talk-heading">Say Hello!</h1>
            <div class="w-form">
              <form id="form2" name="ContactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                <ul class="msgBox"></ul>
                 <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data! </span>
                 <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="form2">
                 <input type="text" class="text-field fname get-fname w-input" maxlength="256" name="yourname" data-name="Your Name" placeholder="Your Name*" id="yourname" required="">
                 <input type="text" class="text-field-2 get-email w-input" maxlength="256" name="email" data-name="Email" placeholder="Email Address*" id="email" required="">
                 <input type="text" class="text-field-3 get-phone w-input" maxlength="256" name="phoneno" data-name="Phone Number" placeholder="Phone number*" id="phoneno" required="">
                 <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="How can we help you? *" maxlength="5000" data-name="Message" required="" class="textarea get-msg w-input"></textarea>
               <!--  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit2" data-wait="Please wait..." class="submit-button w-button"> -->
                 <button type="button">Submit</button>
                 <div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="images/loader-img.gif" /></div>
                 <div class="w-form-done" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
                    <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="w-form-fail" id="w-form-fail" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
                    <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

**contact_form_mail.php**

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("class.smtp.php"); // note, this is optional - gets called from main class if not already loaded

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "Priyanka.M@simformsolutions.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact Form Details";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['yourname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['yourname']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject    = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $comments   = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Contact Form details below.\n\n"."<br><br>";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Your Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n"."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n"."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n"."<br>";
  
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();
    $body             = $output_email_msg;
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                               // 2 = messages only


    $mail->Host="smtp.sendgrid.net";
    //$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username="open_source_simform";
    $mail->Password="open_source_simform57";


    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

    $mail->SetFrom($email_from, $first_name);

    $mail->AddReplyTo($email_from, $first_name);

    $mail->Subject    = "AppVelocity Contact Form Details";

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $address = "priyanka.m@simformsolutions.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

    $formData = $_REQUEST;
    if($formData['fname'] == 'form1') {
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "false";exit;
        } else {
          echo "true";exit;
        }
      } else if($formData['fname'] == 'form2') {
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "false";exit;
        } else {
          echo "true";exit;
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the ajax request firing for all the button click?

Comment: yes... I have used different button for submit contact form on one page..

Comment: Post your javascript code.

Additional Steps for debugging. var_dump $_POST['email'] in index.php to check whether it is set.

Comment: are you using same jquery/js script to trigger the ajax request or different calls, if you are using different calls, check whether you are setting the name of the email field as "email" on the ajax request

Comment: @invalid-bot -- I have attached javascript code mentioned in index.php. Please suggest me.

Comment: @Rakesh -- I have displayed the code. Please check it and suggest me

Comment: Your third form is sending the data of form 2 because the form id there is "form2", other than that the ajax requests are triggering.
And you are missing a closing } in php

Comment: You are sending the data as a get request, and in the php section accessing $_POST

Comment: @Rakesh --- it's not true... currently I want to send the data for 2 form rather than i will work for third form

Comment: @Rakesh- I have send the data for single form but when I try to send the data for two form or multiple form, so i can't get the data

Comment: Add method:post to your ajax call
    url: "contact_form_mail.php",
    dataType: "json",
 method:"post",
    data: formData,

Comment: @Rakesh - Now, here its not working submit button for send data

Comment: hmm there is a form field "subject" in the first form, that is not present in the second. and you are checking the subject in the php if(!isset($_POST['yourname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

Comment: Other than these the forms worked for me with your code

Comment: @Rakesh -- It's not woking for me. Error log like Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(), statusCode: statusCode(), abort: abort(), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(), … }